# Nuget does not download missing packages in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

I go to Tools -> Options -> Package Manager -> Allow Nuget... to have the option enabled already. I opened Package Manager Console and typed `install-package MyPackageName` to install NuGet package successfully, and package folder was created fine. I am pretty sure I have latest version of NuGet installed already.

I closed solution and my VS2010, I deleted package folder, reopen the solution in VS2010, but it does not download any packages at all.

I think I should see a .nuget folder in solution, but it is not there.

Any clue?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to enable NuGet package restore on your solution.
In the Solution Explorer, right-click on your solution and click 'Enable NuGet Package Restore'. This is what will created the `.nuget` directory and add the nuget targets that will drive the package restoration process.

See the [official documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) for a walkthrough.

**Edit: This answer might be somewhat obsolete. MSBuild-Integrated Package Restore is no longer the suggested package restoration option - have a look at either Automatic Package Restore or Command-Line Package Restore on the [official NuGet package restoration documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore). Having said that, MSBuild-Integrated package restore still works, and is still supported.**

Comment: It doesn't seem like VS2013 has that menu option.  [This](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGetEnablePackageRestore) may help.

Answer (score 0):

This two pieces of nuget command saved my life:

```
Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine
Install-Package NuGetEnablePackageRestore
```